# Cannot add Arguments to SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList() in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

For some reason I cannot add anything to an ArgumentList syntax node. I have tried the following examples. In all these cases, a valid Argument node is created however after the Add() operation, the argList.Arguments still has a count of zero.

```
var argList = SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList();
var tempMemAccess = SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(
    SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(ids.First()),
    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(SomeName));

argList.Arguments.Add(SyntaxFactory.Argument(tempMemAccess));
// argList remains empty  
argList.Arguments.Add(
    SyntaxFactory.Argument(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(possibleColName)));
// argList remains empty
argList.Arguments.Add((ArgumentSyntax)base.VisitArgument(a));
// argList remains empty
```

Answer (score 2):

`ArgumentListSyntax` is immutable.

Instead, you should use its member functions to make updated instances with additional arguments:

```
argList = argList.AddArguments(SyntaxFactory.Argument(tempMemAccess));
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently all these objects are immutable so each time I'd have to assign them to a new variable.
This is what I used instead:

```
var newArgs = new List<ArgumentSyntax>();
newArgs.Add((ArgumentSyntax)base.VisitArgument(a));
var argListSyntax = SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList(SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList<ArgumentSyntax>(newArgs));
var newInvocation = SyntaxFactory.InvocationExpression(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("func"), argListSyntax);
```